# calling a javascript function from a ROR controller ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, select, populate, optgroup

I have a function written in javascript that i would like to call (use) in my  ruby on rails controller(.rb). The function dynamically creates and populates a select with optgroup

How would I go about translating this into Ruby code? My problem was finding a replacement for stuff like `document.createElement("optgroup");`

Here's the javascript code:

```
enter function nbFct() {
var clipLists = ["Default", "Recent", "Sticky lists"];
var option1 = ["a", "b"];
var option2 = ["a", "x", "c"];
var option3 = ["f", "e", "c", "d"];
var listType = [];
var optionType = [];
for (var i = 0; i < clipLists.length; i++) {
// create dynamic optgroup from clipLists
listType[i] = document.createElement("optgroup");
listType[i].label = clipLists[i];   
//  alert(listType[i].label) ;
if(listType[i].label ==  "Default"){
    for (var j = 0; j < option3.length; j++) {
// create options and attach to optgroups
    optionType[j] = document.createElement("option");
    optionType[j].value = option3[j];
//      alert(optionType[j].value) ;
    optionType[j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(option3[j]));
    listType[i].appendChild(optionType[j]); 
    }
}
else if(listType[i].label ==  "Recent"){
    for (var j = 0; j < option2.length; j++) {
// create options and attach to optgroups
    optionType[j] = document.createElement("option");
    optionType[j].value = option2[j];
//      alert(optionType[j].value) ;
    optionType[j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(option2[j]));
    listType[i].appendChild(optionType[j]); 
    }
   }
   else{
      for (var j = 0; j < option1.length; j++) {
  // create options and attach to optgroups
        optionType[j] = document.createElement("option");
        optionType[j].value = option1[j];
  //            alert(optionType[j].value) ;
        optionType[j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(option1[j]));
        listType[i].appendChild(optionType[j]); 
      }
    }
  }
 // set the default
 optionType[1].selected = true;
 // clear select menu and append optgroups
 var selectMenu = document.getElementById("clipListOption");
while (selectMenu.hasChildNodes()) {
selectMenu.removeChild(selectMenu.firstChild);
}
 for (var i = 0; i < clipLists.length; i++) {
    if (listType[i].hasChildNodes()) { selectMenu.appendChild(listType[i]); }
  }
}
```

Comment: I disagree with the close votes here. This is a novice's question that betrays something of a misunderstanding about how MVC works, but it's not a _bad_ question on its face.

Comment: yep, kinda unfair... i am new to ROR an JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that easily, except through some exceptionally tortured hacking. In Rails, the controller can't see inside the view. Even if it could, it can't extract Javascript from it and somehow run that in its own local binding context. And even if it could, you wouldn't want to anyway since that's an egregious violation of the **[MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)** pattern.

If you absolutely wanted to do this, it would probably involve a combination of:

- From the client, POST the string comprising the JS function.
- Evaluate and parse the JS.
- Transform the JS into a Ruby string.
- Evaluate the Ruby string in the controller's local context.

That's a lot of work. Instead, a model should be doing the heavy lifting here, and relying on the controller to give it instructions, whose output is then passed to a view.

Comment: i would like to rewrite the code in rail (if it helps!) but i could not find some equivalences.. here is the javascript code: